# Java, how can I popup a dialog box as only an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to find a way to replace all the contents of a JDialog to simply an image.
It's for the about page of a project I'm working on and I want when the user clicks on the About section, an image to popup in the style of a JDialog(and to disappear when focus is lost).
Example: http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/About-Skype.jpg
There Skype displays only an image they've created as their "About" page.
How can I make an "image dialog" in Java(swing)?

Answer (score 6):

> How can I make an "image dialog" in Java(swing)?

Use an undecorated JDialog with a JLabel containing an ImageIcon:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setUndecorated(true);
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
dialog.add( label );
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("myfile.png"));
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, picLabel, "About", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, I have annotated the code for you

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //imports
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class img{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame f = new JFrame(); //creates jframe f

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); //this is your screen size

    f.setUndecorated(true); //removes the surrounding border

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(diceGame.class.getResource("image.png")); //imports the image

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(image); //puts the image into a jlabel

    f.getContentPane().add(lbl); //puts label inside the jframe

    f.setSize(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight()); //gets h and w of image and sets jframe to the size

    int x = (screenSize.width - f.getSize().width)/2; //These two lines are the dimensions
    int y = (screenSize.height - f.getSize().height)/2;//of the center of the screen

    f.setLocation(x, y); //sets the location of the jframe
    f.setVisible(true); //makes the jframe visible


  }
}
```

[[OLD]]
The code below will do what you're looking for.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class img{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(diceGame.class.getResource("image.png")));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lbl, "ImageDialog", 
                                 JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null);



  }
}
```

Comment: That looks great, though what can I do to remove the window borders of the JOptionPane, so that the image is the only thing left?

Comment: Where does the `ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(diceGame.class.getResource("image.png"));` come from, I mean the diceGame explicitly. Why is it not simply "img.class~" as the class is called?